# Setting Up Netbeans with MINGW on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, java-native-interface, mingw

i am currently trying to develop an JNI(Native) component for a Java application, I would like to compile my native components into a Windows DLL, however don't have the time to reinstall windows.
is it was possible to set up MINGW with Netbeans so that i can use the IDE's functions to compile the DLL.

Thanks Lee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This great netbeans tutorial explain how to do and manage crosscompilation of JNI libraries.

http://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/c++/